# passport file can't not read the copmae password fucntion from the schema file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, schema, passport.js

when i try to enter the correct password and email
it gave me an error and the file crashes

here is my terminal error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL99C.png)

and my passport file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCdvi.png)

and the schema file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh6Q8.png)

Comment: Welcome! Please [do not post code, errors and logs as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), but copy the relevant parts into the question instead, refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the Instance method directly without creating a Schema Instance, if you want to access a method like this

```
Schema.compare
```

You need to create a static method in Schema.

Example Static Method Creating :

```
// Assign a function to the "statics" object of our animalSchema
  animalSchema.statics.findByName = function(name) {
    return this.find({ name: new RegExp(name, 'i') });
  };
  // Or, equivalently, you can call `animalSchema.static()`.
  animalSchema.static('findByBreed', function(breed) { return this.find({ breed }); });

  const Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', animalSchema);
```

If you want to read more please follow this [link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics)